# Закодировать URL

Tags: php, url

Есть поиск методом GET.

URL Выглядит так `search?quick=Андрей&q=Поиск`

Как можно зашифровать URL по типу такого:

```
search?c%5Bname%5D=1&c%5Bphoto%5D=1&c%5Bq%5D=Андрей&c%5Bsection%5D=people
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[urlencode](http://www.php.su/urlencode())

Если нужно не ссылки, а именно URL GET параметра:

```
$var = "search?quick=".urlencode(Андрей)."&q=".urlencode(Поиск);
```